# How to display a sized image from Simple Fields repeatable field

Tags: images, plugin-simple-fields

I'm using the Simple Fields plugin (http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-fields/) and am having the hardest time creating a slideshow from a repeatable field group. I've tried piecing everything that I could find from the documentation and from others who have had similar issues, but everything I try results in an "invalid argument" or no image src returned.

This code is working, but I need to know how to tell it to display the 'large' size image:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <?php
        $slideshow_repeat = simple_fields_get_post_group_values(get_the_id(),"Slideshow", true, 2);
            foreach ( $slideshow_repeat as $slide ) {
                $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($slide['Slide']);
    ?>
    <li>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_src[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slide['Title']; ?>"/>
        <h2><?php echo $slide['Title']; ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $slide['Caption']; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $slide['Image Credit']; ?></p>
    </li>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Please always add links to plugins or themes in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to ask a friend to help me get this to work in person. Here's what we changed:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <?php
    $slideshow_repeat = simple_fields_get_post_group_values( get_the_id(), "Slideshow", true, 2 );
    print_r( $slideshow_repeat );
    foreach ( $slideshow_repeat as $slide ) {
        // This is the important bit
        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $slide['Slide'], 'full' );
        ?>
        <li>
            <img src="<?php echo $image_src[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $slide['Title']; ?>"/>
            <h2><?php echo $slide['Title']; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $slide['Caption']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $slide['Image Credit']; ?></p>
        </li>

        <?php
    } ?>
</ul>
```

`$slide['Slide']` was returning the attachment `ID`, so we didn't need to go any deeper in the array to assign the size. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Basically you're now adding the second argument `full`, right? ;) btw, if you want to highlight code parts, please use comments instead of breaking it.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. :) I just didn't know format it properly, apparently. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) without further arguments. The second argument is the `size` and it defaults to `thumbnail`. See source:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size = 'thumbnail', $icon = false )
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, kaiser—link added. I'm still having trouble. Fleshing out the arguments results in no image src being sent through. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) - [blueprint for `wp-config.php`](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/4063197) - and file an [edit] so we can look at your error messages. Next thing: Which size do you call? Is it registered and if yes: Where?